# Firefox shows weird code when all tabs are closed

Tags: firefox, java, javascript

When I close the last tab by clicking on X on Firefox, it displays a long and weird JavaScript from http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/html5player-tr_TR-vflTXVVD8.js. Is this a bug? What does that code mean?

OS: Windows 8
Firefox version: 28.0
Screenies:

[image: s_1]
[image: s_2]

Comment: Well, it’s minified JavaScript from Youtube. According to the file name it’s for an HTML5 player. Your Firefox looks heavily modified. Please list all active extensions. An extension to make this easier is [Nightly Tester Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nightly-tester-tools/).

Comment: Not so modified. My active extensions are listed here: http://i.imgur.com/MU6Dk6h.jpg

Comment: and the location ,  the ytimg variants are all youtube (google server) and flash advertisment. But I think that you already know that. The s.yting one is one that I almost always see trying to store the flash data cookie itself (which is said to be a privacy issue, and might be blocked by privacy things).